# Linkserver update not working in Transaction

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I am trying to do operation on my linked server. I have created one linked server and everything is ok. I just observed one thing which I am not able to understand.

if I run:

```
update SERVER.testdb.[AAA].MyTable
set MyName = 'abc@pqr.com'
where ID = 999
```

This works fine. But when I execute the same code in following way:

```
 BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION TRF

    update SERVER.testdb.[AAA].MyTable
    set MyName = 'abc@pqr.com'
    where ID = 999

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH     
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TRF    
END CATCH
```

It says that the parameter is incorrect.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and what is solution ?

Answer (score 2):

I have tried this on SQL Server 2012. If I run your query as is it completes successfully but does not update anything. But if I do `SET xact_abort ON` it completes successfully. You can read more about `xact_abort` on  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx.

```
SET xact_abort ON 

BEGIN try 
    BEGIN TRANSACTION trf 

    update [SERVER].[testdb].[AAA].[MyTable]
    set MyName= 'abc@pqr.com'
    where ID=999 

    --COMMIT TRAN trf 
END try 

BEGIN catch 
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION trf 
END catch
```

What is the SQL Server version you are trying this on? Also, tell us on which line you are getting incorrect parameter error?